# player level specification for missons in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim when I got the embassy quest in the main missions. When I got into battle with the guards I found them (even a single one) hard to defeat. So I thought I did not have a high enough level (my level was 8). Then I thought of abandoning the mission but I had no saves to load.

1. What should I do now?
2. Is there a reference to know which missions should be started at what level ?
3. I heard enemies get stronger as the player gets stronger. So even if I level up and then get back to this mission it wouldn't help would it ?

Comment: BTW i'am playing it on X-box

Comment: You'll find that you get better answers if you pose clear questions (and preferably only one at a time). I was going to edit your question to clarify it, but I can't tell what the actual question is.

Answer (score 4):

Appropriate player levels for quests and dungeons in general is too complex a topic, for a couple reasons, including:

1. Quests in the main story line or in faction story lines generally have a minimum level.
2. Enemies other than bosses have a minimum and maximum level and are scaled to player level within those ranges.
3. Dungeons are generally scaled to player level when they are entered, but that level is not reset if the player leaves without clearing the dungeon.
4. For some quests, skills or spells used matter more than general player level.

Both the [Elder Scrolls Wiki](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwiyt6aP3PvGAhVIK4gKHbqcCOM&url=http%3A%2F%2Felderscrolls.wikia.com%2F&ei=ulq2VbLyI8jWoAS6uaKYDg&usg=AFQjCNEXjmmQnk35G2JELBB11IL7i3UQfw&bvm=bv.98717601,d.cGU) and the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page) have level information on named quests, dungeons, and enemies. There is also [a page of hints on when to start missions](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quest_Timing) and in which order, although most of the suggestions are vague and more a matter of personal preference.

For the **Diplomatic Immunity** quest specifically, Delphine describes the mission as an infiltration, so it's better to focus on non-violent approaches to solving the mission. Some mix of thief or mage skills are the best options, although potions and enchanted items may offer good substitutes.  Without revealing any spoilers, both character race and gear can help avoid several combats without worrying about either character or skill levels. Only the end of the mission requires combat.

If you need to know enemy level details for **Diplomatic Immunity**, all the enemies are [Thalmor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thalmor), mostly generic types of level 1 through 36 (1 through 44 for Thalmor Wizards.)

Answer (score 0):

Skyrim creatures and npc are leveled, so just coming back later without better gear won't change the outcome, leave the area ond do other quest or look for unique loot

if you feel like "cheating", level up bow skills and get the stealth perk that increases damage when undetected, only dragons can stand more than 1-2 sneak hits in vanilla skyrim

Comment: i'am where the Malborn locks the dor behind me how can i get out ?

Comment: @user119614 Welcome to Gaming SE. Please try to back up your claims with credible source whenever possible.

Comment: @kiyarash You can load an earlier save.

Comment: @Svj0hn, read the whole post. He has no saves to load (although why this is, is beyond my understanding)

Comment: @DangerZone Ah, I see. Better force through it then.

Comment: "so just coming back later without better gear..." -  as if skyrim is about gear. as long as you got equip which is somewhat appropriate for your level you're fine. and coming back later makes things usually a _lot_ easier because you get perks, this point alone is bringing significant advantages. besides that: new shouts can also give huge boosts against certain enemy types. for example: if you play some melee-ish character it is important to get in range with casters before they melt your face off, so a dragon shout that can freeze enemies is completely shifting the balance there.